# Python Memory Usage

Tags: python, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am trying to understand why the memory usage of my program is increasing over time.
I created a program that creates around 200 different instances of class A with two double arrays as properties.

The program is supposed to update A's arrays by popping the last object and prepending a new object.
However, the program keeps getting killed because it uses too much memory.

I am trying to figure out why is that the program's memory usage is increasing even though the size of the objects is supposed to stay the same throughout the whole process.

class A is here https://github.com/Isaacmart/Aztland/blob/main/src/candleStick.py

Comment: We may be able to help if you show some relevant code

Comment: This is the class https://github.com/Isaacmart/Aztland/blob/main/src/candleStick.py

Comment: Probably off-topic: you might find it faster and more convenient to use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=deque#collections.deque) which allows efficient insertion and deletion at both ends of the queue (and also lets you specify a maximum size, useful for fixed-length queues).